# Check if all strings in one array are present in another array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays of strings:

> String[] A = {"AQBC","BSA","BAA"}
>
> String[] B = {"AWF","**AQBC**","SSA","SFW","**BSA**","WQQR","WEWQ","**BAA**","RDR","GGWQ","GQEW"}

I want to check if all elements of array A are in array B. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: The easiest would be to use `Set`s; build `setA` and `setB` and check that `setB.containsAll(setA)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(B).containsAll(Arrays.asList(A));
```

The easiest. Not the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Converts your arrays into set to remove possible duplicated elements ans then [`containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) returns `true` if `setB` contains all of the elements of `setA`:

```
Set<T> setA = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(A));
Set<T> setB = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(B));
setB.containsAll(setA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this is to make String Array A and B compare in a array. and sort them

String[] A = {"AQBC","BSA","BAA"}

String[] B = {"AWF","AQBC","SSA","SFW","BSA","WQQR","WEWQ","BAA","RDR","GGWQ","GQEW"}

compareStringArray(A, B, true);

public static void printArrayListOfString(List Al) {

for (int i = 0; i < Al.size(); i++) {

```
if (i != 0) {

  System.out.print(", ");
}

System.out.print(Al.get(i));
```

}

System.out.println();

}